# How to set session timeout in sitecore for the visitors to the site

Tags: session-state

I have tried the below configs. But still, it is not working.

```
<setting name="Authentication.ClientSessionTimeout" value="180" />
```

```xml
<authentication mode="None">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="180" />
</authentication>
```

```xml
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" cookieSameSite="None" timeout="1" sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager, Sitecore.Kernel">
```

Is there any other config file in Sitecore where I need to set the timeout value for Asp.net SessionId?

Comment: Do you have analytics enabled? Also, check if you have VisitorIdentification included.

Comment: Try this. In the `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config` there is setting for `ExpireTimeSpan` for `CookieAuthentication` and `PreviewCookieAuthentication`. Update them and check if it works.

Comment: @PrashantTomar yes analytics is enabled and included visitorindentification also.

Comment: @SumitBhatia I have updated the ExpireTimeSpan in Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config. Still the session is not getting expired.

Answer (score 1):

In order to modify a user session default timeout, you would need to adjust the following settings:

**In CM server -**

1. in the file `\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config` update setting `ExpireTimeSpan` for `processor name="CookieAuthentication"`.

**In Identity Server -**

1. in the file `\sitecore\Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer\Config\identityServer.xml` update the settings `CookieLifetime` and for `defaultClient` update setting  `IdentityTokenLifetimeInSeconds`
2. Restart the Identity server app service.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `timeout="1"` is enough to make sure that contact session lasts 1 minute.

You don't need anything else unless you have login mechanism and you want to make sure that contacts are logged out.

I can see that you configured `regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"` which can mislead to wrong impression that it's the same session while indeed it's a new session with the same session id. Try changing that attribute to `false`.

Comment: in my case the anonymous user browses around my site and i want to retrieve the user values when the session ends.

Comment: And how you try to retrieve the data? Is there any user data in your xDB?

Comment: I'm inheriting this pipeline ConvertToXConnectInteractionProcessorBase. so once the session ends the pipeline has to get triggered. Then i'll get some values from args like pageevents and some more. But the session is not getting expired. 

Can you tell me exactly in which table in need to check for user data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify that you have restart the application after saving the `web.config` correctly.
2. Also please make sure there are no `patch files` overring setting .
3. Check for any `analytics` or custom logging code that may conflicts with the session lifetime.
4. Try setting `regenerateExpiredSessionId="false"` to maintain the same ASP.NET session ID when the session is renewed.
5. Ensure the browser `cookies` are not cleared or blocked when testing session by any security concerns or settings.You can test this by verifying that the `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie is being set correctly.

I hope this helps you troubleshoot the issue and please provide further info if new findings.